# Query a data set from previously retrieved records?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I'm learning ASP.NET with C# backend. I am trying to run a "query of queries". (At least that's what I was taught it was called in college in PHP.)

I have a record set (the grade of a particular student) that has been retrieved via SQL statement. That statement has a 'Student ID' and their grade. Now in separate database, in a table I have the Students name along with their Student ID.

I want to have the data base pull the grade record, then query the students name table and also show the name of the student based upon the retrieved records student ID.

I know I can create a new recordset for the students name, and then pass the query parameter of the retrieved ID on to the new SQL query. How is that formatted? Is there a best practice?

Here is what I am using to pull the students grades.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="rs_ViewGradeData" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PDACConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * 
                     FROM [tblGrades] AS t 
                    WHERE ([studentID] = @studentID)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="studentID" QueryStringField="sid" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The students database is on the same server, just a DIFFERENT database.

Is it not possible to just to pull out the studentID from the the query above and use it as parameter for the query below? I used the AS in the above query and am attempting to use it below.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="rs_Students" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBStudentsConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [userID]
                        , [userFName]
                        , [userLName] 
                     FROM [tblStudents] 
                    WHERE [userID] = @[t.studentID]"
    OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="studentID" Name="studentID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Just join the student name table to the grade table using the student id and return all data at the same time.

Comment: once you have your recordset or dataset look up how to use the `.Select()` method to search

Comment: Another tip: try not to use * in your selects and just return the fields you are going to use.

Comment: why do you feel the need to make multiple trips to the database rather than just getting all the data in one shot?  Yes you can take the use the same id to run both queries, I just don't understand why you'd think that was beneficial in any way?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT g.StudentId, g.Grade, sn.Name 
FROM db1.dbo.tblGrades g
INNER JOIN db2.dbo.tblStudentName sn
    ON g.StudentId = sn.StudentId
WHERE (g.studentID = @studentID)
```

Comment: I think you blew my mind with this one. I grasp the concept, but let me see if I can clarify. In your example, is there two other queries that took place prior to running this statement? G and SN?

Comment: g and sn are just alias names for the 2 tables

Comment: this is just one statement, you don't need to create 2 queries to pull back related data, just one with the relation specified.

Comment: But I would have to create two connections thought correct?

Comment: no, you can get them in a single call.  If the databases are on 2 seperate servers, just have the admin create a linked server and you can query across that as well.

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?